# Stop Facebook and Instagram from running in background

Tags: facebook, background-process, instagram

In developer settings I can stop both Facebook and Instagram but those pesky apps just bounce right back within seconds.  One reason I moved from Apple to Android was to be able to control my device and I find this frustrating.  Is my only option to delete these apps and just run them from a mobile web browser?

I don't want to be told that these apps need to be running all the time and I can just ignore it.  They can run when I start them until I close them.  This is for data, privacy and battery usage concerns whether real or perceived I want this control of my device.

Also I do not want to root my phone and keep the OS stock.  Running 7.1.1 on a Nexus 5x

Comment: You can install [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) to prevent these apps from running in the background. If something else than tapping on the app starts the app again Greenify will notice and it'll give you the option to cut off this wakeup path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applications like Facebook messenger, always leave a few processes and services running in the background. Even using task killers is not very effective in preventing them from running, because soon they will continue running.

In a situation like this, hibernating is more efficient because it takes care of both the proceses and services running in background. It will also prevent that application from starting up again until you start it.

Having said that a good remedy is to use hibernation applications like [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) and see if it resolves the issue. The good news is that it is available for non root users as well.

More detailed instructions for setting up are found here: [How to Optimize Your Android Phone’s Battery Life with Greenify](https://www.howtogeek.com/198135/how-to-optimize-your-android-phones-battery-life-using-greenify/)

Comment: Greenify asks for some low level permissions and basically has access to my entire system.  I did not feel that great about using it, perhaps this and deleting the app are the only ways.

Comment: Do you have any other solution in mind ? In that case please feel free to write your own answer:) otherwise you may tick to accept this answer. AFAIK these permissions are needed for Greenify to work properly (same as you get when using other 3rd party tools to achieve this). What permissions are you sensitive with ? Besides hibernation is the most effective was to stop background applications from running.

Comment: My final solution is just to delete Facebook and Messenger entirely from my phone as Greenify is just another problem in my opinion.  The reduced data and time wasted looking at Facebook while I am out and about is a great reward.

Comment: Glad you chose the best way to deal with this once and for all :)